# Add TITLE and COMMENT metadata to .MOV video file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, video, vlc-media-player, metadata

1. In Windows 7, I load a .MOV video file in VLC Mediaplayer.
2. In VLC, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to show the Media Information dialog of this file:

   [image: Media Information dialog]
3. I enter a new TITLE and a new COMMENT in the respective fields and then click the **Save Metadata** button.
4. Then I close and reopen VLC with this video file. In the Media Information dialog I can see that the metadata previously entered are not there, obviously they have not been saved.

Is this a bug in VLC?

How can I save my own metadata (Title and Description/Comment) to .MOV and other video file formats with VLC (or with any other (free) program)?

Comment: are you on Windows?

Comment: Hi! Yes, as I wrote in my question: Windows 7.

Comment: True, was just in a hurry to get to your problem that i skipped the intro :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this article [here](http://www.videouniversity.com/articles/metadata-for-video/)

Proposes the following software:

- On the Mac see [MetaZ](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/36029/metaz).
- For PCs check out [Daminion freeware](http://daminion.net/download)
- For Flash videos, you can use [FLVmeta](http://code.google.com/p/flvmeta/downloads/list)
- Another freeware program that can write metadata for video files is called [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool).

UPDATE: as posted in the comment: Unfortunately, Daminion only generates proprietary metadata inside its cataloging program, it does not store metadata inside the file. So the article is misleading. However I've found a program which works perfectly: [**MetaX on PC**](http://www.danhinsley.com/index.html). (user1580348)

Comment: Unfortunately, Daminion only generates proprietary metadata inside its cataloging program, it does not store metadata inside the file. So the article is misleading. However I've found a program which works perfectly: MetaX on PC. http://www.danhinsley.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right-clicking the file and going to the "Details" tab in the Windows Explorer dialog that opens? There should be some spots to add properties to items, and this is the supported way to do this.